# Implementing traits for strong types with C++ concepts

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

I would like to have a nice way to enable functionality(e.g. ++, *=, /) of my strong types(e.g. StockPrice, Count).

I don't like using inheritance for that ([CRTP/mixins](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/12/12/mixin-classes-yang-crtp/)), I understand some may like it but I prefer to not use inheritance for this use case.

So I have code like [this](https://godbolt.org/z/7GsoPMcbr):

```
template<class, template<class...> class>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization = false;
template<template<class...> class T, class... Args>
inline constexpr bool is_specialization<T<Args...>, T> = true;

template<typename Underlying, typename TagType>
struct StrongT{
    Underlying val;
    using Tag = TagType;
};


template<typename T>
concept addable =  is_specialization<T, StrongT> && requires (T& t){
    typename T::Tag::addable_trait;
};

struct IndexTag{
    using addable_trait = int;
};

using Index = StrongT<size_t, IndexTag>;

struct NanosTag{
    using addable_trait = int;
};

using Nanos = StrongT<size_t, struct NanosTag>;

template<addable T>
T operator + (const T& a, const T& b){
    return T{a.val+b.val};
}
```

I like it since I can list my "traits" in tag struct, but I dislike it since it is a bit spammy. I can not declare tag struct inline like this:

```
 using Nanos = StrongT<size_t, struct NanosTag{/*...*/}>;
```

So is there way to do what I want in a shorter way, without using inheritance?

note: I only have one trait/concept here, obviously I want many traits supported, e.g. comparable/incrementable...

Comment: You want to avoid all inheritance, everywhere? Or would it be ok to compose the trait tags with inheritance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like

```
// Different capability tags
struct Addable{};
struct PreIncrementable{};
// ...

template <typename Underlying,
          typename TagType,
          typename... CapabilityTags>
struct StrongT
{
    Underlying val;
    using Tag = TagType;

    friend StrongT operator+(const StrongT& lhs, const StrongT& rhs)
    requires((std::is_same_v<Addable, CapabilityTags> || ...))
    {
        return T{lhs.val + rhs.val};
    }

    StrongT& operator++()
    requires((std::is_same_v<PreIncrementable, CapabilityTags> || ...))
    {
        ++val;
        return *this;
    }

    //...
};
```

and then

```
struct NanosTag;
using Nanos = StrongT<size_t, NanosTag, Addable /*, ..*/>;
```

Comment: Not sure if `TagType` is even still needed, but maybe it also had other purposes.

Comment: @aschepler: `TagType` is for the "name".

Comment: If we want to define non-member functionality outside the definition of `StrongT`, we could have `StrongT` add a public `using capabilities = std::tuple<CapabilityTags...>;`, and other declarations can constrain using that. And/or `template <typename Tag> static constexpr bool supports = (std::is_same_v<Tag, CapabilityTags> || ...);`

Comment: @aschepler A tag type makes the type unique.  Without it, two different Strong types that were int and Addable would actually be the same type.

Comment: I like this answer!  However, I would change it from `std::is_same_v` to `is_convertible_v` (and reverse args) which would allow composing capabilities into groups (via inheritance) so strong type declarations could use the group (once) and get all of the capabilities.  https://godbolt.org/z/bhYhzMeer

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis: it is indeed adaptable. OP wants to avoid inheritance though.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis: As state before, `TagType` is to have unique type, so using `MyNumTag` for all your example defeat that purpose (even if capabilities make the types unique in your cases) ;-)

Comment: @Jarod42 I saw that, but permitting it doesn't force its use.  Also, it is not clear if the OP's restriction was that the StrongT type itself avoided inheritance, or if the sets of capabilities must also avoid it.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes I reused the tag in a context where it was guaranteed that the combination of template parameters would be unique, as it was a family of distinctly different capabilities.  But if you want to use different tags I have no objection.  Just don't declare the tags inside the parameter list of the declaration of the StrongT and I'm happy.   =)

Comment: I think usage IS to declare the dummy struct inside parameter list...

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis OP did not think about that, but my main motivation is to avoid ugly inheritance for users, I guess for traits it is fine... I wish C++ had a way to do + on types, without the need for inheritance, like almost a literal concat of members, but it does not. :)

Comment: @Jarod42, the point of Strong Types is to increase code safety, and there is a certain flaw in declaring tags inside template types that can change the meaning of your strong type to be NOT as strong as you think.  It can also introduce undefined behavior.  Code being added to a header that you directly (or indirectly) can break your strong type in subtle and surprising ways.
https://youtu.be/26-7V8M1TmQ Shameless plug. :)

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis I have seen your video before, but it is one of those things like using underscores in google test name: I can live with that risk. :) But anyway nice video since I never knew about this before I saw your video. If I worked in aerospace or something like that where C++ nonsense can kill people I would obviously behave differently.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, what you are looking for is a way to make sure and even enforce programmatically that a class implements some functionality without inheritance. One possible way to do this is to create a `concept` that requires this functionality and then use `static_assert` to validate the class in question provides the functionality.

Example:
Say we want a class that has the `++` and `--` operators we'll have to declare a concept like this:

```
template<typename T>
concept ExpectedTraits = requires(T t) {
    t++;
    t--;
};
```

Then if we want to assert that (for example) class `Object` has the desired traits, we need to assert it -

```
static_assert(ExpectedTraits<Object>);
```

If class `Object` doesn't support `++` and `--`, this assertion will fail and the code won't compile until `Object` supports these operands.